# How to check data in Jest

Tags: javascript, types, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm using the Jest package to test my Node application server-side.
I need to check the value and type of the result from my request to the server.

1. Is it possible to expect the result to be an object like this?
2. And how to check `string[]` ?

The result is from the request:

```
{
  "definitions": [
    "One who subsists on charity; a dependent. South."
  ],
  "pos": "n.",
  "word": "ELEEMOSYNARY"
}
```

My check to be:

```
definitions - string[]
pos - "n."
word - string
```

My code is :

```
** expect(typeof (res.body.definitions)).toEqual('string'); ???? **

expect(res.body.pos).toEqual('n.');
expect(typeof (res.body.word)).toEqual('string');
```

Comment: Your code is not working?

Comment: it word but like this : 
```expect(typeof res.body.definitions[0]).toEqual('string');```

can i check if array is - ```srting[]``` ?

Comment: Yow i came for a similar question.. I needed to check if it was or not a string.. and your code (third one) is not working for me.. but i founded the way ```expect(typeof (res.body.word)).toBe('string');```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of definitions or check if `Array.isArray()` is true, and also the string at position zero like this:

```js
// Either this for the array check
expect(res.body.definitions.length).toEqual(1);
// Or this for the array check
expect(Array.isArray(res.body.definitions)).toStrictEqual(true);

// And this for the string check of the array
expect(res.body.definitions[0]).toEqual("One who subsists on charity; a dependent. South.");
```

I'm assuming you have this api request/response mocked so you can rely on the value of `definitions[0]` to check the string.

Comment: but the array is not always length 1, it can be 4 or 5 - Depending on the selected word and its definitions

Comment: In your tests, you should be mocking the data and testing your logic. If you need to check 4 or 5 length arrays, you know what inputs would cause that and mock those so you can test that your code is functioning properly. So your test should have fake data like "I know with this input, I will expect to get an array of 4 strings that look like this" and build that into your test. Are you trying to test against a live api response?

Comment: I do check for information I have in the data,
The problem is that it's a test that tests me for a "random word," meaning each time I get a different word. So I can not compare the mock I have with the information that comes back

Comment: If it takes a random word and you get a different word, there has to be some business logic that says "when given X, expect Y" and THAT is what you want to test, including multiple tests if there are multiple inputs and outputs. eg, when given "take", expect an array with 6 elements. when given "fern", expect an array with 2 elements. You have to have known inputs and expectations in order to test. Now those known inputs could be random - ie, a + b = c. "When given a and b, expect c to equal a + b" and you can run anything through that. But you can't test pure randomness with unknown results.

Comment: Yes I understand you, my question is if I can check the tape of the definitions that comes back to me please, the type is string[]